# Is there any SMS service which must use a carrier to receive sms from a notification service and forward to a http end point

Tags: notifications, sms, twilio

My requirement is to subscribe a notification service like [IPN](http://www.incidentpage.net/) with a phone number owned by a sms service(US) like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com) and forward to an http end point. But the problem with twilio is, there will not be any **carrier** for the virtual phone number allotted. also IPN only allows to send sms to a phone number with a carrier. So the subscription is not possible.

Can anyone suggest a sms  service which is using a carrier to receive sms?

Or is there any alternative to override this in twilio with IPN?

Comment: What makes you think there won't be a carrier for a Twilio number? This is the carrier information I got returned for a Twilio number:

_Twilio - Inteliquent - SMS-Sybase365/MMS-SVR_

Have you tried to sign up? I punched in a random unassigned US Twilio number and it claimed to have sent me a sign up code, but I don't have a US number to confirm it works.

Comment: I tried to subscribe the IPN service using virtual twilio number, but I am not getting the otp to verify in the twilio number (Tried with carriers: AT&T, Verizon Wireless, Sprint, and T-Mobile USA).